# Non-static method Stevebauman\Purify\Purify::clean() should not be called statically

Tags: php

I am not good at php, I just installed SMM php script. I runned into this error whenever I try to create a category. Please help me fix this.

Error Title: Non-static method Stevebauman\Purify\Purify::clean() should not be called statically

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq48D.png)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.